# Отключение сервиса после выхода из приложения

Tags: java, android, android-service

Здравствуйте мое приложение запускает сервис который должен в фоновом режиме выполнять определенную работу. Это код запуска сервиса в активности(в проекте всего одна активность):

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , MyService.class));
        }
    }).start();
```

Это код самого сервиса:
public class MyService extends Service {

```
public static final String TAG = "fmproducts/service";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG , "create");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG , "onStartCommand");
    task();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG , "destroy");

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
private void task(){
    query();
}
```

Происходит destroy как только приложение отключается я даже пробовал добавить в активность

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e(MyService.TAG , "restart");
    // функция запуска активности есть выше
    start();
}
```

объявление в манифесте

```
        <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Ничего не помогает. Перезапуска сервиса не наблюдаю. Как можно решить проблему чтобы сервис не отключался?

Comment: START_STICKY по описанию перезапустит onStartCommand при создании нового экземпляра сервиса. Мне кажется в первую очередь Вам нужно понять почему сервис вообще останавливается - он не должен этого делать при корректной работе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо вызывать Foreground service - что бы гарантировать работу сервиса. У Foreground service приоритет как у запущенного приложения, у остальных как решит система, понадобиться ресурсы телефона - убивает сервис.
Почитайте тут https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызывать

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , MyService.class));
```

без Thread